# Simplify the logorithmic expression

Tags: logarithms

I have the following equation describing frictional losses in a pipe for fluid flow.
$$
\frac{1}{f} = -2 \cdot \log_{10}\bigg(\frac{\frac{r}{2 \cdot r_w}}{3.7} + \frac{2.51}{\text{Re}\cdot \sqrt{f}}\bigg)
$$

In the above equation $$r, r_w$$ are constants - lets say equal to $1$. $\text{Re}$ is the Reynolds number that will be updated over time with the available information. The unknown is $f$ in the above equation and I am not sure how to simplify this expression so that I can write a C++ code.

I tried to input constants and use the desmos online plotting tool which works but in my case as $\text{Re}$ keeps changing consequently $f$ is not a constant value anymore.

Comment: I don't see a good way to simplify here, maybe this is a bit brute-force-ish but I might just say screw it and slap numerical methods on it.

Comment: @StephenDonovan There is an explicit solution